# css rollover buttons- great in safari,and firefox/ ie but not chrome?

Tags: css, rollover

i've been trying out a bit of code posted to make image rollover buttons using only css,

this seems to work fine.

local testing showed no problems, IE, Firefox, safari all ok. even chrome displays as intended on the local version.

Once i move to a hosted test, IE, Firefox and Safari all display as intended but chrome offsets all the buttons right about 8-10 pixels.

here's the test page

http://www.fierysurprise.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/bga/bgd.html

can anyone enlighten me as to what's happening?

site built in Kompozer

Comment: I don't see the problem. Latest version of Chrome, on Vista.

Comment: works fine on Chrome 6.0.472.0 dev / Ubuntu Lucid - there should be more contrast around the rollovers to signify that there is something there to be rolled over, since you didn't ask.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the squares under the "architectural design..." phrase.

I can't recreate this problem in Chrome v5.0.375.125.

What version of chrome are you using?  Chrome tends to doggedly cache resources.  Have you tried a cache refresh?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Chrome are you using? I looked at your site in Chrome 5 and can't seem to tell a difference between any of the browsers you've mentioned.